# C++ Producer / Consumer multi threads pattern with maximum container size

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, producer-consumer

I've just written a **Producer / Consumer** pattern templatized that should work in multi threads environment (IE producer(s) and consumer(s) in separate threads).

The original use case is one producer and one consumer in separate thread with a limit of container size.

It should work for a multi producers / consumers case though.

***[EDIT 1]***: it appears to not working at all with multi consumers

Standard used is **C++ 14**

My question is about the correctness of the `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` instructions and `synchronizer.wait` ones.

I have also a question about the forward declaration of templates, is there a way to avoid it without having a compiler error in the linking step ?

And last question about the handle of the container (the list), it must become the owner of the elements and handle its life time so what's the method signature I have to use (`const T &e`, `T e`, `T &&e`, ...) ? Or even `std::move` and implementation of perfect forwarding, I don't know.

**ProducerConsumer.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef CUDA_HARDWARE_VIDEO_READER_PRODUCERCONSUMER_HPP
#define CUDA_HARDWARE_VIDEO_READER_PRODUCERCONSUMER_HPP

#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>

template<typename T> class ProducerConsumer
{
    public:
        explicit ProducerConsumer(ulong maxSizeInBytes);

        void produce(const T &element);
        T    consume();
        void producerIsOver();
        bool isFinished();

    private:
        std::queue<T>           queue;
        std::condition_variable synchronizer;
        std::mutex              mutex;
        bool                    producerOver;
        ulong                   maxSizeInBytes;
};

#endif //CUDA_HARDWARE_VIDEO_READER_PRODUCERCONSUMER_HPP
```

**ProducerConsumer.cpp**

```cpp
#include "ProducerConsumer.hpp"

/**
 * @brief Constructor
 *
 * @tparam T - The type of element's container
 * @param maxSizeInMB - The maximum size the container can have in bytes
 */
template<typename T> ProducerConsumer<T>::ProducerConsumer(ulong maxSizeInBytes): maxSizeInBytes(maxSizeInBytes), producerOver(false) { }

/**
 * @brief Producer - add element in the list
 *
 * @tparam T - The type of the element
 * @param element - The element to add
 */
template<typename T> void ProducerConsumer<T>::produce(const T &element)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    // Block the thread until the size of the queue allows to add more elements in it
    if (sizeof(T) * (queue.size() + 1) > maxSizeInBytes) {
        synchronizer.wait(lock, [&]() {
            return sizeof(T) * (queue.size() + 1) <= maxSizeInBytes;
        });
    }

    queue.push(element);
    synchronizer.notify_one();
}

/**
 * @brief Consumer - Get an element of the list and wait for it if the list is empty
 *
 * @tparam T - The type of the element
 *
 * @return The element
 */
template<typename T> T ProducerConsumer<T>::consume()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    // Block the thread until the queue is empty and the producer has finished to fill the queue
    if (queue.empty() && !producerOver) {
        synchronizer.wait(lock, [&]() {
            return !queue.empty() || producerOver;
        });
    }

    T element = queue.front();

    queue.pop();
    // Wake up the producer if he's waiting
    synchronizer.notify_all();

    return element;
}

/**
 * @brief Tells the producer has finished to fill the container
 *
 * @tparam T - The type of element's container
 */
template<typename T> void ProducerConsumer<T>::producerIsOver()
{
    // @todo Useless ?
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    producerOver = true;
}

/**
 * @brief Tells if the whole process is over (IE producer has finished to fill the container and the container is empty)
 *
 * @tparam T - The type of element's container
 *
 * @return True if the whole process is over, false otherwise
 */
template<typename T> bool ProducerConsumer<T>::isFinished()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    return producerOver && queue.empty();
}

// @todo Annoying forward declaration there ...
template class ProducerConsumer<long double>;
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ProducerConsumer.hpp"

/**
 * @brief Test the producer / consumer pattern that preserves order and is limited in size
 *        Required output is :
 *        Consume 1,
 *        Consume 2,
 *        Consume 3,
 *        ...,
 *        Consume 20
 *
 * @return EXIT_SUCCESS if no error occurred
 */
int main()
{
    ProducerConsumer<long double>           container(sizeof(long double));
    std::random_device                      randomDevice;
    std::mt19937                            randomGenerator(randomDevice());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> distribution(10000, 1000000);

    randomGenerator.seed(std::time(nullptr));

    std::thread producer([&]() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 21; ++i) {
            usleep(distribution(randomGenerator));
            container.produce(i);
        }

        container.producerIsOver();
    });

    std::thread consumer([&]() {
        do {
            usleep(distribution(randomGenerator));
            std::cout << "Consume " << container.consume() << std::endl;
        } while (!container.isFinished());
    });

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your edit places the question on the edge of what is considered [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, since it seems like the code is not working as intended. Against this background, pleace check if your code is ready to be reviewed in full here.

Comment: @Alex Hello, actually my code is working for the primary job I stated. You can execute the main and it is working as intended. I thought it would work for a larger scope but it is not. This point is "on topic" because: _Questions about improving scalability are allowable, as long as your code works for small inputs._